# max number of connected sockets vs. values of SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I have more than 3 million file descriptors on a Linux machine, so I look how socket buffers size against RAM size would constrain the maximum number of simultaneous tcp connections that the machine can handle. If you had similar experience, please, advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about RAM size, but rather about virtual memory size.  Clearly you cannot have buffers exceeding the total virtual memory available on the computer.  That said, if you are finding that things start to break when you have three million sockets open, you may be better off focusing your efforts on reducing the number of sockets if you can, rather than reducing the buffer sizes--three million sockets is an awful lot, and may suggest some other issues with your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Linux default send and receive buffer sizes as they were some years ago:

```
3,000,000 x 43,689 + 3,000,000 x 16384 = 180,219,000,000
    = 175,995,117 Kb
    = 171870 Mb
    = 167 Gb
```

This is indeed rather a lot. Unless you really have this much virtual memory and indeed address space available you aren't going to get to 3 million open sockets.

Comment: this is reverse of what i asked: i asked not to consider number of file descriptor as a limit, point out how to calculate linux memory available for socket buffers, and divide it by RCV+SND buffs size to elicit a rough limit